# Iterating nested list inside-out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python nested list structure:

```
test = ['a', ['c', ['e'], 'd'], 'b']
```

or the same, just formatted:

```
test = [
    'a', 
        [
            'c', 
                [
                    'e'
                ], 
             'd'
        ], 
    'b'
]
```

I was wondering what the best way would be to iterate over the complete list, starting with the innermost nested list object ('e') to the outermost list ('a', [...], 'b') in reversed order. A call to reversed(test) just doesn't do the trick with nested lists. And it should be able invoke a callback function on every depth of the iteration.

The iterations should look something like this ([xx] == computed value from previously invoked callback):

```
1st e --> callback(e)
2nd c [e] d --> callback(c [e] d)
3rd a [c e d] b --> callback(a [c e d] b)
```

Hope this explains my problem & thanks for your help

Comment: Is flattening the list not an option?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Flattening would loop over `[b, d, e, c a]` instead.

Comment: I also tought that this might help. The problem is that i have to calculate every nested list-item with a callback function. After flattening i have no idea which item should be calculated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a *postorder traversal* of the structure:

```
def traverse(l):
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            traverse(x)
    callback(l)
```

If `callback` is defined as `print`, we get

```
['e']
['c', ['e'], 'd']
['a', ['c', ['e'], 'd'], 'b']
```

Comment: Thank's, this looks simpler than @Abhijit answer.

Comment: Note that type checking isn't pythonic - and using `isinstance(x, list)` means this won't work with tuples, for example. Do also note that this is a recursive function, meaning that if you have *huge* lists, you could end up hitting the maximum recursion depth. It's also likely to be relatively inefficient.

Comment: @Lattyware: `isinstance(x, list)` can easily be changed to `isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)`, in any case, user's example only deals with lists.

Comment: @Lattyware: If you are dealing with lists nested deeper than 1000 levels, you will probably have other problems. (Hell, Python's parser gives up on literals nested that deep). I argue it is pretty efficient -- the other solution may use a lot of extra memory for the queue, but this one goes only to the maximum depth of the structure. If you want to avoid recursion, it is trivial to rewrite with an explicit stack.

Comment: @nneonneo: I would argue against your statement `the other solution may use a lot of extra memory for the queue`. The other solution also goes till the maximum depth and uses **at-most** as much memory as required in your recursive solution. Both the solution have pros and cons, the reason I deliberately opted out from a recursive solution is, you cannot use it as a generator. Passing a callback to the function or calling from within IMHO not a good option.

Comment: Now I see it. But I don't think that can answer the OP's problem, because it specifically *only* recurses on the second element of every list, unless that's what OP actually has as the data structure. My solution is intended to iterate completely arbitrary nested lists inside-out.

Comment: @Abhijit, Lattyware: In this case using `collections.Iterable` would not be ideal. We do *not* want to iterate over strings!

Comment: I use `isinstance(x, (list, tuple))`. Might not be ideal, but does the trick. Once again, both answers would work for my problem. If I could accept both, I would...

Comment: @Lattyware: follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961601/isinstancex-list-when-iterating-a-list-containing-strings-and-lists

Comment: @nneonneo Then check if it's an iterable, but not a string. That way there is still flexibility. I'm not saying there is never a case for type checking, but in this case, we can improve it to allow more flexible input.

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution I would propose is

```
>>> def foo(test):
    queue = []
    try:
        while True:
            queue.append(test)
            test = test[1]
    except IndexError:
        for e in reversed(queue):
            yield e


>>> data = foo(test)
>>> next(data)
['e']
>>> next(data)
['c', ['e'], 'd']
>>> next(data)
['a', ['c', ['e'], 'd'], 'b']
>>> next(data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#753>", line 1, in <module>
    next(data)
StopIteration
>>>
```

How it works

1. Traverse depth-first, and push the elements in a queue
2. Loop through the reversed queue and yield the elements

Comment: Note that this can be simplified down in Python >= 3.3, `for e in reversed(queue): yield e` is equivalent to `yield from reversed(queue)`.