# isinstance(x, list) when iterating a list containing strings and lists

Tags: python, collections, iterable

At [Iterating nested list inside-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960380/iterating-nested-list-inside-out/14960687#comment21002419_14960687), I was told that "type-checking isn't Pythonic". Generally, this is true: we want to look only at the interface (duck-typing) rather than a specific type.

The question asks about nested lists of the form `['a', ['c', ['e'], 'd'], 'b']`, and we specifically consider strings atomic (non-iterable). So, we can't use a blanket `collections.Iterable`, but on the other hand `isinstance(x, list)` does seem a bit hacky.

My answer was

```
def traverse(l):
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            traverse(x)
    callback(l)
```

What's a better approach? Or is `isinstance` OK here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that your answer is OK here -- Although I might change it to

```
if not isinstance(x,basestring):
   ...
```

to make it a little more accepting depending on the expected input.  Ultimately, some problems you need `isinstance` which is why it still exists in the language.

That being said, the thing about this problem that is un-pythonic is the data-structure.  In python, if a problem seems really hard, it probably means you're storing the data in the wrong way ... (Of course, I realize that you had no control over what the original poster of the other question's data structure was ;-).

Basically, I guess that my view is that `isinstance` is the **hack** that you need to make lemonade when your colleagues/some library writer somewhere gives you lemons -- Otherwise you avoid it where possible.